# $2$ part of $Ext(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}, A)$ when $A$ is finite

Tags: number-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors, hom-functor

Let $A$ be a finite group. Let denote $Ext^1$ by $Ext$ functor in homological algebra.

Is $(Ext^1(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}, A))[2]$ finite?

When $A$ is finite cyclic group $\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$, $\#Ext^1(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}, A)=gcd(2,\#A)=gcd(2,m)$. Thus  $(Ext^1(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}, A))[2]=1 \text{or}    2$.

But is  $(Ext^1(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}, A))[2]$ finite in the case  $A$ is not cyclic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Actually, the whole Ext group is finite, even without limiting to the $2$-torsion. This group classifies extensions $G$ of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by $A$, i.e. exact sequences
$$
0 \to A \to G \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0
$$
There are only finitely many things $G$ can be (only finitely many group structures on a finite set) and only finitely many index two subgroups such a $G$ can have.

Comment: In the case $A$ is infinite, do you know any condition  of $A$ such that $Ext(Z/2Z,A)[2]$ is finite ?

Comment: What in my mind is $A=H^1(G_K,E)/Sha(E/K)$ where $G_K$ is a absolute Galois group of a number field and $Sha(E/K)$ is a Tate-Shafarevich group of elliptic curve $E/K$. But any kind of condition of $A$ is also appreciated.